# Inconsistent results with Meteor's pub/sub feature

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, publish-subscribe

I'm experiencing inconsistent results with Meteor's pub/sub feature, and I suspect it's a source of confusion for a lot of developers hitting the threshold of an MVP built in Meteor becoming a production app.

Maybe this is a limitation of MergeBox:

Let's say I have a collection called `Events`, in which I have document-oriented structures, ie, nested Array, Objects.  An `Events` document might look like so:

```
// an Events document //
{
  _id: 'abc',
  name: 'Some Event',
  participation: {
    'userOneId': {
        games: {
          'gameOneId': {
            score: 100,
            bonus: 10
          }
        },
        {
          'gameTwoId': : {
            score: 100,
            bonus: 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    'userTwoId': {
        games: {
          'gameOneId': {
            score: 70,
            bonus: 15
          }
        },
        contests: {
          'contestOneId': [2, 3, 6, 7, 4],
          'contestTwoId': [9, 3, 7, 2, 1],
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

So at these events, users can optionally participate in games of certain types and contests of certain types.

Now, I want to restrict subscriptions to the Events collection based on the user (show only this user's `participation`), and, sometimes I'm only interested in changes to one subset of the data (like, show only the user's scores on 'gameOneId').

So I've created a publication like so:

```
Meteor.publish("events.participant", function(eventId, userId) {
  if(!Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId})) return this.ready();
  check(eventId, String);
  check(userId, String);
  const includeFields = {
    name: 1,
    [`participation.${userId}`]: 1
  };
  return Events.find({_id: eventId}, {fields: includeFields});
});
```

This publication seems to work fine on the client if I do:

```
// in onCreated of events template //
template.autorun(function() {
  const 
    eventId = FlowRouter.getParam('id'),
    userId = Meteor.userId(),
    subscription = template.subscribe('events.participant', eventId, userId);
  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const event = Events.findOne({_id: eventId}, parseIncludeFields(['name', `participation.${userId}`]));
    template.props.event.set(event);
  }
});
```

Happily, I can use the Event document returned that includes only the `name` field and all of the user's `participation` data.

But, later, in another template if I do:

```
// in onCreated of games template //
template.autorun(function() {
  const
    eventId = FlowRouter.getParam('id')
    gameId = FlowRouter.getParam('gameId'),
    userId = Meteor.userId(),
    subscription = template.subscribe('events.participant', eventId, userId);
  if(subscription.ready()) {
    const event = Events.findOne({_id: eventId}, {fields: {[`participation.${userId}.games.${gameId}`]: 1}});
    template.props.event.set(event);
  }
});
```

I *sometimes* get back the data at `event.participation[userId].games[gameId]`, and sometimes I don't - the Object that's suppose to be at `gameId` is non-existent, even the it exists in the Mongo document, and the subscription should include it. **Why?**

The only difference is between the two calls to `Events.findOne()` is that in the latter, I'm not requesting the `name` field. But, if this is a problem, **why?**. If minimongo already has the document, who cares if I request parts of it?

The subscriptions in both templates are identical - I'm doing this because the `games` template is available at a route, so the user could go straight to the games url, by-passing the `events` template altogether, so I want to be sure the client has the document it needs to render correctly.

The only way I've gotten around this is to make a straight Meteor method call to the server in the games template to fetch the subset of interest, but this seems like a cop-out.

If you've read this far, you're a champ!

Comment: If the only difference is not getting the `name` field from minimongo, and it doesn't work, surely the workaround would be to just use the same `findOne` call?  Or does it not work with the same `findOne` call here?  It seems extreme to revert to using `Meteor.Method` calls to get data that is already in minimongo just to avoid adding the `name` field into `template.props.event`

Comment: Just an observation that from a modeling pov, the pattern of using a *value* (like a document *_id*) as a *key* generally gets people into trouble. It makes the document schema dynamic. You typically want to use an array of objects in those cases.

Comment: @Michel Floyd Thanks! I suppose it also depends on your design. Document databases can be used schema-less.